# gradle docs missing simple way for me to call ant build from my build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle

Based on this importing seems like a pain and won't always work

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/attempting_to_import_ant_build_file_fails

Then, there is a whole page on ant tasks being used only if imported in their docs here in chapter 20

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#ant

but what I don't see is a smiple way to just invoke ant(and when I tried the exec, it failed :( :( ).  How can I just wire up a subproject's ant file for now so I can move on?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: I've found that using ant from gradle (both using tasks and importing a build file) works great. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please include code you tried. 'ant(' does not seem like the correct syntax.